# sharethis Option showing a Privacy Popup how to disable this

Tags: javascript, sharethis

I have integrated the https://sharethis.com and i have the We value your privacy in my screen any one have idea how to disable this ?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's legal to disable this in your jurisdiction? Also, did you check [their FAQ](https://sharethis.com/support/faq/gdpr-compliance-tool-faq/) to see if this is answered there?

Answer (score 4):

On FAQ you can find more information about GDPR and e.t.c. But popup you can turn off on the https://platform.sharethis.com/gdpr-compliance-tool in option:

> WHICH USERS SHOULD BE ASKED FOR CONSENT (display the CMP when they
>   appear on the page for the first time)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The whole popup is in div,

```
<div class="popup_popup" style="display: flex;"></div>
```

That's why You need to put css in main.css

```
.popup_popup {
    display: none !important;
}
```

This is working for me. :)